# Is there any way to convert a multiple ASCII characters into a string of numbers?

Tags: python, string, ascii

I have a string of characters

```
ascst = 'abc'
```

and I want to know how to convert it into a string of numbers

```
'097098099'
```

in the output, every 3 letters is an Ascii character.

097 being a, 098 being b, 099 being c.

Is there any easy way to do this?

Comment: Apply function `ord` to each character, join the results.

Comment: There is, but what have you tried and what precisely is the problem with it?

Comment: I got it working :D